# Is pandas converting a column of lists into floats after the dataframe reaches a certain size?

Tags: python, pandas

I am try to use pandas to analyze the Ao3 dataset. Specifically I am trying to track the growth of the ten largest fandoms. To do this I need to see if any given work has one of those ten fandoms. The initially provided form for the tags is weird but I have converted it to a list for each work. To determine if one of the ten fandoms is in that list I made a simple list comparison function and am using the .apply method to apply it to each row. I first tested this on a single month of data and it worked fine. When I attempted to use it on a single year is when the problem arose. Attempting to run the function on a whole years worth of data leads to an error. “Float” object is not iterable. This is strange as the object for the column is a list. I believe that this is a problem of scale as the size of the data frame for 1 year is 1.6 million rows. My working theory is that at a certain size pandas converts each list into a float. Can anyone confirm this and if so do you have a work around.

I have tried using smaller dataframes and this works.

Comment: No, that's clearly nonsense.  A pandas column must all be of the same type.  Have you printed the problematic rows?

Comment: I do not believe that it is any one row that is the problem. I can run the function for any given month but not for the whole year

Comment: Have you tried extended the list until it fails?  You should be able to narrow it down through divide and conquer.

Comment: I found the issue. There was a single null value in one of the rows. After dropping that value the code runs fine. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that there was a null value in one of the cells for the column. After removing the value the code ran fine.